# New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster "R Server" ClusterTier powershell

Tags: r, powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to create a Azure R Server HDInsight Cluster via PowerShell.

I am using the cmdlet - `New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster`.
It is throwing the following regardless of the `-ClusterTier` (The only choices appear to be Standard and Premium);

> New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster : BadRequest: Cluster type 'R Server' is
> not supported by 'Standard' tier.

Is it possible to create a HDinsight R Server cluster via powershell and if so what are the correct settings for `New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster`?

Comment: Have a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-powershell. There are instructions for how to set up, in PowerShell a new R Server on an HDInsight cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for creating R Server clusters via PowerShell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-powershell#create-cluster-configuration-object).